# OpenGL triangle strips have artifacts (missing triangles)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am using a nice little line rendering library that utilizes GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS to make smooth lines (described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226569/Drawing-polylines-by-tessellation)).  The lines look great EXCEPT that there are random missing triangles.  See image at below link.

[image]

Since I have not seen any other complaints on the blog for this software, I am thinking there might be something wrong with my OpenGL state that is causing this, but I don't know what.  Disabling GL_CULL_FACE had no effect (though my understanding is that all triangles in a strip must face the same way anyways) and I am low on ideas.

Comment: This seems to be some floating point round-off error. Since when I zoom in on your image, I see exactly three triangles missing; if a vertex is degenerate i.e. same as one of its counterparts you'd only get a line out of it. Did you try with straight lines first, for debugging purposes? Because the artefacts seem to be only in fairly straight portions of the strip.

Comment: This looks like there is a duplicated vertex in the sequence; it's highly unlikely to be anything related to round-off error.  If you're using an indexed method for rendering (e.g., `glDrawElements`), look for duplicate sequential indices.  If you're using `glDrawArrays`, look for duplicated vertex positions.